# Multi-Thread Programming

Tags: c, multithreading, posix

Is there a function call that can associate with a specific thread to make the thread run or wait?  I have 4 threads in my program and I am trying to figure out a way to tell any one of the threads to wait or run when I want them to.

Comment: You'd probably have to setup a mini-messaging queue that each thread polls to determine what it is suppose to do.

Comment: there is not something like  pthread_cond_wait(The thread you want to  wait ) ---- I know thats not correct use for that function but its just to give an example

Answer (score 2):

Your question is quite general. It really comes down to: Review the pthreads documentation.

If what you want is to have thread A wait for thread B to finish, check out `pthread_join()`.

If what you want is to have thread A wait until thread B says it's okay to continue, you will need a mutex and a conditional variable. Check out `pthread_cond_wait()` and associated functions.

Comment: Apparently I need to type faster. Agreed - especially on pthread_cond_wait(), which is what I think they're looking for.

Comment: Yeah, I am trying to pause a thread before finishing,  let another thread run (2nd thread) , pause the second thread, let the third thread run...ect ... If that makes any sence

Comment: @MRP, as you are describing it, it doesn't. If each thread must run after another has finished, then there is little reason to use threads.

Answer (score 0):

A common mechanism for handling multiple threads is a master/slave approach where one thread hands off tasks for others to perform. The crux to this style, which I think is what you're getting at, is to realize that *even in the slave threads, each thread inherently has total control over its own execution*. The master doesn't really "force" the other threads to do anything, the master can make a request but the slave thread must **voluntarily** accept direction from the master... hrm... so maybe master/slave is a misnomer here... Anyway, The common solution for the slave threads is in pseudocode

```
while (!should_exit):
    while (!have_something_to_do):
        wait_for_something_to_do()
    do_the_thing_i_was_waiting_for()
```

You can implement this strategy quite easily in C using a structure like the following (I'm resorting to pseudo-c-ish code for the example's sake though)

```
struct Slave {
    Mutex              thread_lock;
    ConditionVariable  thread_cv;
    int                exit_flag;
    void             (*thread_operation)();
};

void slave_thread( Slave * slave ) {
    while( !exit_flag )
    {
        lock( thread_lock );
        while( slave->thread_operation == NULL )
            slave->thread_cv.wait( thread_lock );
        unlock( thread_lock );
        (*slave->thread_operation)(); // do the master's bidding...
    }
}

void master_thread()
{
   Slave slave1;
   Slave slave2;

   slave1.thread_operation = NULL;
   slave2.thread_operation = NULL;

   // create the threads. They'll immediately block on the condition variable

   slave1.thread_operation = some_function_pointer;
   slave2.thread_operation = some_other_function_pointer;

   notify_one( slave1.thread_cv ) // Now that the function pointers are set, wake
   notify_one( slave2.thread_cv ) // the slave threads

}
```

It's an overly simplistic example, of course, but hopefully it'll give you the general idea.

Comment: So if i understand correctly, the master thread controls a pointer which tells the slave thread to run next.

Comment: @MRP: You need to change the way you think about it - instead of thinking that the master thread tells the slave thread to execute, the master thread puts some work in the slave's "in-box", and the slave runs while there's some work for it to do.

Comment: Ok than kyou that makes more sense